# Побитовые операторы(практическое применение)

Tags: битовые-операции

Зачем нужны побитовые операторы (практическое применение)?

Comment: кажется мне что видел я уже тут такой вопрос

Comment: [Побитовые операторы](https://learn.javascript.ru/bitwise-operators)

Comment: Нажмите на тег [Битовые-операции], который поставили, там масса примеров их применения